# find Vector2 libgdx

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx, vector, linear-algebra

I need to get coorinates of **red** point. Coordinates are just for example, it would be better to see the common formula. Found code like this, but it gains wrong result.()

```
Vector2 o = new Vector2(6f,2f);
Vector2 n = new Vector2(1f,4f);
Vector2 v = new Vector2(3f,2f);
Vector2 A = n.sub(o).nor();
float t = A.dot(v);
Vector2 result = A.scl(t);
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're trying to _project_ the point (3,2) on the line (1,4)-(6,2). You could take a look [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Orthogonal_Projection_Onto_a_Line) or ask [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=project+point+on+a+line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code I can't tell what the `ownerv` vector is so I can't tell you why it's giving you the wrong result.

But to do it from scratch, according to [Wikipedia's article on vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection), you can do the following;

1. Create a vector **a** that is the direction from **o** to **v**.
2. Create a vector **b** that is the direction from **o** to **n**.
3. Let **d** be the *dot product* of **a** and **b** divided by the length of **b** (this will give you a scalar that is the distance from **o** in the direction of **b**).
4. Create the result, **target**, by adding a vector of length **d** to **o**.

In code those steps could look like this;

```
Vector2 o = new Vector2(6f, 2f);
Vector2 n = new Vector2(1f, 4f);
Vector2 v = new Vector2(3f, 2f);

// The direction from o to v
Vector2 a = (new Vector2(v)).sub(o);

// The direction from o to n
Vector2 b = (new Vector2(n)).sub(o);

// d is the length along b where the project a will fall.
float d = (new Vector2(a)).dot(b) / b.len();

// Take the vector that is the normal of b, scale it by d and add it to the start point o, 
Vector2 target = (new Vector2(o)).add(b.nor().scl(d));
```

(Note that you probably don't want to new up as many `Vector2`s as I do in this example in your actual game code).